# About a script in .sh

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

since yesterday I've been trying to run a command in my script called `sed` it processes a text and don't tell me that there is any errors but when I check inside the file it just suppresses the text that was supposed to be replaced.

Can someone help me with this ?

Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bienvenue dans l'outils d'ajout à la base de données sur les Animés"
echo "Pour commencez veuillez taper le titre de l'animé dans ce format-ci"
echo "exemple_pour_tester ; Sans majuscules ni espaces"
cat ~/mal-project/anime_template >> ~/mal-project/sources/anime-list
    echo -n "Mal-Database ->"
            read ${titre}
            echo "processing..."
            sed -i "s/{titre}/${titre}/" ~/mal-project/sources/anime-list
```

Comment: Please have a look at "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."  Also, I doubt that `read ${titre}` what you want.  Lastly, there is no way to tell whether the `sed` command does what you want without having a sample input file and your desired output file.

Comment: I tried the command manually and it worked perfectly.
It doesn't always need and in and out input

Comment: In this case at least, that is not true.  Without your sample input, there is no way of knowing whether you actually have the curly braces in your input file.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question is not related to Ubuntu but would fit better to [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major issues in your script.

1. to read something from stdin and put it in a variable called `titre` you need

   ```
   read titre
   ```

   (without a preceeding `$`). This will put your input into 
   the variable `$titre`.
2. To replace the literal word `titre` with the content 
   of the variable `$titre` you need

   ```
   sed -i "s/titre/$titre/" ~/mal-project/sources/anime-list
   ```

---

The curlies (`${titre}` vs. `$titre`) are only needed to make clear where a variable ends if the situation is ambigious. Consider you want to replace the literal `titre` with the content of the variable `$titre` ***plus*** the text `deux`. The naive approach would be

```
s/titre/$titredeux/
```

But here `titre` would be replaced with nothing (empty string) because there is no variable `$titredeux`. Hence, we write

```
s/titre/${titre}deux/
```

instead to make clear that the variable is actually just `$titre`.